# Creating a Surface and Rectangle Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a class surface that takes

- `self.rect` - that is a rectangle object and
- `__init__(self, filename, x, y, h, w)` - Takes the `filename` string as a parameter and saves it to the `self.image` instance variable
- Takes a `x,y` set of coordinates, as well as `h, w`, and creates a `Rectangle` object stored in `self.rect`
- `getRect` - that returns the rectangle object

```
class Surface:
    def __init__(self, filename, x, y, h, w):
        self.image = filename
        self.rect(x, y, h, w)
    def getRect(self):
        return Rectangle()
```

I imported my file Rectangle.py that is

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, h, w):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
    def __str__(self):
        return "(x:)"+str(self.x) + ", y=" + str(self.y) + ", width:" + str(self.w) + ", height:" + str(self.h)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
    import Rectangle.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Rectangle.py'; 'Rectangle' is not a package
```

Since Rectangle has init(self, x, y, h, w), don't I have to return Rectangle()?

Comment: You don't `import Rectangle.py`, you would `from Rectangle import Rectangle`, which means "from Rectangle.py import the Rectangle class"

Comment: The most common problems people have these days is to try Python without read the Tutorial section of the documentation, to begin with. This is what questions like this one exposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.rect()` isn't a function of `Surface`, and your import statement isn't correct.

Sounds like you wanted this

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle

class Surface:
    def __init__(self, filename, x, y, h, w):
        self.image = filename
        self.rect = Rectangle(x, y, h, w)
    def getRect(self):
        return self.rect
```

However, a "getter function" doesn't add anything here